# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method open on channel razorpay_flutter)

Tags: flutter, razorpay

```
Reloaded 7 of 542 libraries in 1,099ms.
E/flutter ( 1062): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method open on channel razorpay_flutter)
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 1062): #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod[39;49m
E/flutter ( 1062): <asynchronous suspension>
[38;5;248mE/flutter ( 1062): #1      Razorpay.open    (package:razorpay_flutter/razorpay_flutter.dart:48:35)[39;49m
[38;5;248mE/flutter ( 1062): #2      _BuyBidsState.openCheckout[39;49m
[38;5;248mE/flutter ( 1062): #3      _BuyBidsState.getBidsData.<anonymous closure>[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 1062): #4      _InkResponseState._handleTap[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 1062): #5      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure>[39;49m        
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 1062): #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 1062): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 1062): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 1062): #9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 1062): #10     GestureArenaManager.sweep[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 1062): #11     GestureBinding.handleEvent[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 1062): #12     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 1062): #13     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 1062): #14     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 1062): #15     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 1062): #16     _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1138:13)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 1062): #17     _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)    [39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 1062): #18     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 1062): #19     _invoke1  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:273:10)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 1062): #20     _dispatchPointerDataPacket  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:182:5)[39;49m
E/flutter ( 1062):
```

I am getting this error while integrating the razorpay with flutter.I have written the code correctly or not.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();

 _razorpay = Razorpay();
 _razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_PAYMENT_SUCCESS, _handlePaymentSuccess);
 _razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_PAYMENT_ERROR, _handlePaymentError);
 _razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_EXTERNAL_WALLET, _handleExternalWallet);
}

@override
void dispose() {
super.dispose();
_razorpay.clear();
}

 void openCheckout() async {
 var options = {
  'key': 'rzp_test_geinuADCB6Csdb',
  'amount': 10*100,
  'name': 'BidAnd2Win',
  'description': 'Buying Bid to play game',
  'prefill': {'contact': '8888888888', 'email': 'test@razorpay.com'},
  'external': {
    'wallets' : ['paytm'],
  }
 };
try{
 _razorpay.open(options);
}
catch(e) {
  debugPrint(e);
}

}

void _handlePaymentSuccess(PaymentSuccessResponse response) {
  Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Success' + response.paymentId);
}

void _handlePaymentError(PaymentFailureResponse response) {
  Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Failure' + response.code.toString() + " - " + response.message);
}

void _handleExternalWallet(ExternalWalletResponse response) {
  Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Sucess Wallet payment' + response.walletName);
}
```

At first i am getting error when initState() is called for all these three methods 
      [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No      implementation found for method open on channel razorpay_flutter)

then for second method

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method resync on channel razorpay_flutter)

and for the third method

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method resync on channel razorpay_flutter)

I have also added my razorpay_flutter correctly but when I click the button and call the method openCheckout() then missingPluginException occurs. How to fix this unhandled Exception error i have already called _razorpay.open(options) in try and catch block

Comment: just run flutter packages get once

Comment: @Divyanshu - did it work?

Answer (score 2):

**flutter clean, and restart, then it ok**

I found it at: [enter link description here](https://github.com/PonnamKarthik/FlutterToast/issues/97) and it worked fore me just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced same issue on another flutter package. The main reason of issue that after PUB GET new package, what use MethodChannels, you need to do next steps:

Uninstall the app from your device.
Rebuild app again.
This should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Roll back to version 1.1.1

or just replace the existing plugin with **razorpay_flutter: 1.1.1**

(make sure you do not have the ^ before the version number)

Answer (score 1):

After hours of searching I finally managed to get a proper solution for this:
Step 1:make a file name of proguard-rules.pro inside android>app
that should be : android/app/proguard-rules.pro then paste below code inside proguard-rules.pro file

```
 -keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}

-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-dontwarn com.razorpay.**
-keep class com.razorpay.** {*;}

-optimizations !method/inlining/*

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  public void onPayment*(...);
}
```

Step 2:
go to android>app>build.gradle and find buildTypes
inside buildTypes>release add some lines

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled false
        useProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Step 3(IMP): Check your app is Signed perfectly using https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android
If not then follow the steps in above url

PS: Used razorpay_flutter: 1.1.1

I hope this steps will solve the existing problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and for me it did not work when built desktop APK or on simulator. But worked on real device by changing min sdk version 19

Answer (score 0):

for me, I just used `flutter clean` and then built `flutter build` or `flutter run`, and it started working fine!